# Submissions using JSON:API POST method

Tags: webforms, 9

I would like post submissions in webform using core's JSON:API. I've created a webform, then added the fields I need. I've installed [JSON:API Extras](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_extras) to be able customize some API properties per resource. I'm able to create submissions, override the remote address, post the referenced entity except to the field values.

I've also tried a couple of data formats, but still no luck.

Here's what I've done so far.

**Headers**

- api-key: 4bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
- Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
- Accept: application/vnd.api+json

**POST URL**

```
http://example.com.com/api/webform_submission/contact
```

**POST data**

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "webform_submission--contact",
        "attributes": {
            "entity_type": "node",
            "entity_id": "5",
            "remote_addr": "",

            // Format 1
            "email": "example@example.com",
            "name": [{"value": "Loremipsum"}],

            // Format 2
            "data": [{
                "email": "example@example.com",
                "message": ["Please ignore this email."],
                "name": [{"value": "Loremipsum"}],
                "subject": "Testing contact webform"
            }],
            
            // Format 3
            "data": [{
                "email": "example@example.com",
                "message": "Please ignore this email.",
                "name": "Loremipsum",
                "subject": "Testing contact webform"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

**Results**

```
{
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "meta": {
            "links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://jsonapi.org/format/1.0/"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "data": {
        "type": "webform_submission--contact",
        "id": "035de1b3-01ef-49a9-89ab-3bf8b2b641ea",
        "links": {
            "self": {
                "href": "http://example.com.com/api/webform_submission/contact/035de1b3-01ef-49a9-89ab-3bf8b2b641ea"
            }
        },
        "attributes": {
            "serial": 211,
            "drupal_internal__sid": 62,
            "token": "xjIywCTtW9gqpgnYIAtVIIO_LpUB7pKIKnYfjIf1Z8U",
            "uri": "/api/webform_submission/contact",
            "created": "2020-11-05T01:26:51+00:00",
            "completed": "2020-11-05T01:26:51+00:00",
            "changed": "2020-11-05T01:26:51+00:00",
            "in_draft": false,
            "current_page": null,
            "remote_addr": null,
            "langcode": "en",
            "entity_type": "node",
            "entity_id": "5",
            "locked": false,
            "sticky": false,
            "notes": null
        },
        "relationships": {
            "uid": {
                "data": null,
                "links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://example.com.com/api/webform_submission/contact/035de1b3-01ef-49a9-89ab-3bf8b2b641ea/relationships/uid"
                    }
                }
            },
            "webform_id": {
                "data": null,
                "links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://example.com.com/api/webform_submission/contact/035de1b3-01ef-49a9-89ab-3bf8b2b641ea/relationships/webform_id"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://example.com.com/api/webform_submission/contact"
        }
    }
}
```

Drupal version: 9.x

Webform version: 6.0.0-alpha20

JSON:API Extras version: 8.x-3.16

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

According to the issue, [Support submitting webforms through JSON API](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2913865) Closed (won't fix)

> POSTing a WebformSubmission entity requires an administrative
> permission (or requires crafting custom access hooks)
>
> [image]

The expectation is to use the contrib module [Webform REST](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rest) instead.